# Wireless Access Point stopped working unexpectedly

Tags: wireless-networking, router, lan, wireless-access-point

I have a simple LAN set up at home using a Linksys WRT54GSV4 as my primary router and an Encore ENHWI-2AN3 as an access point. I connect the Encore to the Linksys by running a cable from one of the Linksys LAN ports into the Encore WAN input.

I originally configured this using the Encore setup wizard, setting the device up in AP Router Mode. It detected the input network and worked about as expected, creating a second network that used my primary network to connect to the internet.

It worked fine for about 2 weeks, then abruptly cut out today. I checked to make sure the network was still live through the cable going into the Encore (provides internet when connected to a laptop directly) and that devices are still able to connect to the network being broadcast by the Encore.

When I try to rerun the connection wizard on the Encore, I receive the message "No Services found in WAN port." The WAN Settings is no longer retrieving a dynamic ip from the line. I tried providing a static IP, assigning an IP address within the subnet range of my primary router that wasn't being used and pointing the Default Gateway to the Linksys IP, but this did not work either.

When I plug the cable into the WAN port, an internet light comes on that is not lit when a live network is not connected.

I've tried doing a hard reset on the Encore (held down the rest button until the lights flashed, reconfigured from scratch), but the WAN settings are still not detected. Also tried powering off and on the modem, linksys, and encore.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up testing the Encore as a normal router - it failed to detect WAN settings even when connected directly to the modem.  Replaced the item with a dedicated wifi access point and that seems to work fine.